# Как правильно написать jQuery скрипт под такую задачу?

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать jQuery скрипт. Нужно, чтобы при заходе на [эту](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/lechenie-narkomanii.html) и [эту](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/vazhno-znat.html) страницы средствами jQuery заменить значение класса

`.contentwidthr{width:70% !important}`

на

`.contentwidthr{width:100% !important}`

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location == 'lechenie-narkomanii.html') {
        $(".contentwidthr").css("width","100% !important");
    };
    if (window.location == 'vazhno-znat.html') {
        $(".contentwidthr").css("width","100% !important");
    };
});
```

Comment: Код не работает, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте на тестовой странице или тут: http://jsfiddle.net/ получить точно рабочий скрипт, а потом перенести на свой проект. Я тоже так бодался с js, оказалось, что был конфликт при добавлении библиотек js, т.е. скрипт был рабочий, но не работал на моем проекте, потом методом тыка понял, что конфликтует и заменил библиотеку на другую.